# Using both Laravel and non-laravel-PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to make Laravel work with a non-laravel script.

I need Laravel to handle only routes that are set in the web.php file, and allow anything else that's not defined to be handled by my non-laravel-PHP's legacy_index.php.

[image]

This is the folder setup that I have in my public.
**legacy_index.php** is the one that belongs to my non-laravel-php script. The legacy_index.php script has a URL parsing algorithm in it.
I want Laravel to allow me to use the **legacy_index.php** if the path I am trying to access is not declared in the routes, but without showing the **legacy_index.php** file in the link.

As an example:
Laravel would process these routes:

- 127.0.0.1:8000/api/getUserData
- 127.0.0.1:8000/api/getAppointments

But would ignore these routes:

- 127.0.0.1:8000/mail
- 127.0.0.1:8000/user-profile

And would let my **legacy_index.php** to handle the routing for these two.

I have tried by editing the .htaccess file, trying to redirect to these links from the routes, but nothing worked.

Did anyone do this before and has any tips/pointers?
I am developing on Windows, using Laravel 8.42.

Comment: What about using a [fallback route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#fallback-routes) that utilized your legacy_index.php's code?

Comment: When I had a legacy project I ended up putting all routes in web.php also in .htaccess so the rest of them went to my legacy code. This is not something I recommend and would urge you to just make @shaedrich's suggestion work since that is going to save you a lot of headaches

Comment: @shaedrich thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a shot that way. I've tried to search for something that would catch routes which are not defined, but I wasn't able to find the fallback route. Must've missed it.

Comment: @RăzvanT. We've all been there in some way. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your routes are neatly identified by the a simple rule that if they begin with "/api" then you want Laravel's index.php to handle it but if it doesn't then you want legacy_index.php to handle it. Therefore adding another conditional rewrite rule to the .htaccess might be 1 method.

```
...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index_legacy.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked, but I also added a check in server.php that would redirect to Laravel's index if I had api/ in link, or to my index otherwise. Thank you!

Comment: Glad my solution was a good fit for your project. Alternative solutions — if your hosting provides sufficient configurability — is to run the API over a different port. 8008 and 8080 are common alternatives. Or use sub-domain for the API routes. If none of the routes in the API are going to be accessed by the end-user via a browser then the slightly uglier URLs are not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Migrating Legacy Web Applications to Laravel](https://www.phparch.com/2019/03/migrating-legacy-web-applications-to-laravel/) might be useful to you.
See `Step Three: Hand Off to Legacy Framework`